# Xsim Exercise without numbering

Tags: numbering, exercises, scripts, xsim, hide

I use xsim to create exams and it works very well. I kove the way it handles exercises and solutions.  Now I'm starting to create a script and I was wondering if there is a way to hide the numbering in exercises so I can just write an unnumbered exercise and hide the solution for the students but leave a blank space for them to write in.